# Como converter comprimento de onda para RGB?

Tags: c#, java, c, algoritmo

Alguém conhece algum algoritmo que realize a conversão de um comprimento de onda para RGB?

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472514/convert-light-frequency-to-rgb

Comment: Obrigado @cantoni!

Comment: Sugestão genérica, só para constar: converta o comprimento de onda para o "hue" do sistema HSV, e então converta HSV para RGB. Lembrando que RGB mostra inúmeras cores impuras, enquanto um comprimento de onda é uma cor pura, então tais cores teriam S=1.0 e V=0.5 no sistema HSV. Ainda com este sistema acho que pode haver algum problema com os violetas,